# How to automatically restart Flutter APP if the user exits the application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter menu app android for a restaurant. The user will check the dishes on the tablet screen, if the user somehow returns to the device's home screen, I would like to restart the app automatically after some time returning to the app's home screen, for example.

I can already start the application automatically when someone turns off the device. Thanks to  to everyone

Answer (score 0):

The thing what you r looking is "kiosk mode". https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pub.dev/packages/kiosk_flutter&ved=2ahUKEwi10-jDtqHvAhWqxoUKHY5YAj8QFjAAegQIARAC&usg=AOvVaw1gwQqs5Ep1oOfjNKbv-z5-